# Cordova Android Classification as Malware

Tags: android, cordova, security

I made a Cordova App with Version 5.2.0
A friend of me send me a Picture that states (freely translated from German):

> AVG AntiVirus FREE Alert
>
> App is classified as Malware. Click on Deinstallation to remove the App

Does anybody know where this comes from? Of course I implemented no Malware. Google only gave me this [article](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/trend-micro-discovers-apache-vulnerability-that-allows-one-click-modification-of-android-apps/?_ga=1.87516625.854897669.1441971922) and it is up to Cordova 4.0.1
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: can you provide more information? Did you send your friend a .apk or he installed it from google play? The AVG antivirus that claims that is on desktop or on the mobile?

Comment: Beta Android through PlayStore. You can check it here: http://bit.ly/1MXFavt
And the AVG antivirus runs on mobile

Comment: I've just installed your app and avg said it's safe

Comment: ok thank you. I will check. Don't have AVG on my Testdevice but will download it. Than I am pacified :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution for us Cordova developers is to move up to 4.0.2: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/05/26/android-402.html

Comment: I am on Android Platform Version 4.1.1

Comment: Hmm... according to that press release, the security issue should be resolved. Maybe AVG needs to update things on their end?